# Python and using data from Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm wondering what's the best way to analyse data being pulled from Google Sheets. I've successfully managed to connect to a specific sheet and return all data using:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('KB Swings').sheet1


total_swings = sheet.get_all_records()
print(total_swings)
```

But I want to do a basic sum of data in a specific column.

Comment: Doing sums is what spreadsheets are good at... do you even need Python for this?

Comment: I am then using the result elswhere.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to analyze tabular data in python is pandas: 
[Here is a short introduction.](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-pandas-in-python-b06d2dd51aba)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want but have you considered computing the sum in your spreadsheet?

```py
    #get column values in column n
    col_vals = sheet.col_values(n)
    # sum of list
    col_sum = sum(col_vals)
```